# I have a problem with react-print not printing the dimensions i want

Tags: react-to-print

So i have a resume creator app and when the user is finished he can store his resume in pdf. It works pefectly in a wide screen like a monitor but on a phone it doesn't.Now that happens because i have made the Resume look differently when a user is on a phone or a computer and that makes the print look different also. So question is, is there a way that i can make the pdf always have monitor dimensions?

I haven't found anything on the internet yet for this particular problem.

Comment: Hello. You can _attempt_ to hint to the browser the page size using the CSS [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size) directive. For example, to only set the size while printing: `@media print { @page: { size: A4 }}`. Note that this is only a hint. Not all browsers will respect this unfortunately, and mobile browsers in particular are not very print friendly. (Note: I maintain `react-to-print` :)

Comment: Hello. I used it and it works perfectly. Thank you very much man :).